# C# get word after specific string with spaces new lines etc

Tags: c#, string, substring

Hello i have a string like this :

```
adidas Ultra Boost

DNA Marimekko (W)

Size: 6.5W

GZ8686

€146

€35

€105

snowflake

 €111

90 days




adidas Ultra Boost

DNA Marimekko (W)

Size: 8W

GZ8686

€146

€43

€126

snowflake

 €102

14 days
```

And the results from this string should be like this :

```
string Size1 = "Size: 6.5W";
string Price1 = "€146";
string time1 = "90 days"

string Size2 = "Size: 8W";
string Price2 = "€146";
string time2 = "14 days"
```

I try with substrings etc and can't get final result just. How can i accomplish that?
It's harder because we have a lot of new lines and spaces here. I'm looking solution to get this values from string like this.

Can someone help with that?
thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have had better luck with parsing the complete html you stripped this text out of.

Comment: It's just example i don't want work with html , only string just.

Comment: Well, you just make your life harder. In HTML you could look for a table and read it out. Good luck doing that on the text provided. You could try and parse relative to words of the title row of what once has been the table.

Comment: Not harder i just want to find it in this way.

Comment: It _is_ harder. In HTML you would find a table, make sure it's the one you want, then read out the rows, done. You would probably already have 5 answers on how to do it. In free text - not so much. The solution will be much less generic and will need a ton more effort. But anyway, if this is what you got, then it is what it is. What have you been trying so far?

Comment: You say it's just an example. How similar are those examples?

Comment: How about something like https://dotnetfiddle.net/JCXWbL ?

Comment: Well first off you probably want to make it a list of a class instead of string variables (as I assume you don't know the size). Then read the lines one by one, skipping the ones you dont want or are blank. As others said, from a table is probably easier.

Comment: Be aware that the code in the fiddle is extremely brittle. It doesn't account for any deviation from the "10" fields per item pattern and does not do any validation, whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like dotnetfiddle.net/JCXWbL ? –